# Cannot assign must be instance on form save

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm creating a site where users can publish their content, each content redirect to a private user to user chat depending on the content id.

I'm doing it like this so I can retrieve the content infos on the private chat.

The problem is that when a user submit the form to post a `comment` I get this error :

> Cannot assign "< User: my_user >": "userComment.seller" must be a "Profile" instance.

On my view, I'm saving the connected user as a `buyer` and the user who will receive the comment as `seller`.

How can I fix this error ? What am I doing wrong on the code below ?

here is **models.py** :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True)

class Gig(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class userComment(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="buyer", null=True)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="seller", null=True)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def addComment(request, gig_id):
    gig = Gig.objects.get(id=gig_id)
    username = gig.profile.user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = userCommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(buyer=request.user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    else:
        form = userCommentForm()
        form.fields['seller'].initial = username
```

**forms.py**

```
class userCommentForm(forms.Form):
    seller = CommaSeparatedUserField(label=_(u"seller"))
    comment = forms.CharField(label=_(u"comment"), widget=forms.Textarea())

    def save(self, buyer):
        sellers = self.cleaned_data['seller']
        comment = self.cleaned_data['comment']
        message_list = []
        for seller in sellers:
            msg = userComment(buyer=buyer, seller=seller, comment=comment,)

            if seller == buyer:
                print('-----------------------------------------------')
                print('same')

            if None is not None:
                msg.parent_msg = None
                None.save()
            msg.save()
            message_list.append(msg)

        return message_list
```

---

**Traceback :**

```
File "C:\Python34\projects\tryTen\private_comment\views.py" in addComment
  31.             form.save(buyer=request.user)

File "C:\Python34\projects\tryTen\private_comment\forms.py" in save
  15.             msg = userComment(buyer=buyer, seller=seller, comment=comment,)
```

Comment: Check the type of `seller`. and a way to convert it to type `Profile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `userComment` model has the feild `seller` as a foreign key to another model named `Profile`. But the instance of buyer passed in `msg = userComment(buyer=buyer, seller=seller, comment=comment,)` is of type `User` and not of type `Profile`.

Either modify 
`seller = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="seller", null=True)` to `seller = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="seller", null=True)` 
or
retrieve and pass a `Profile` instance.

```
p = Profile.objects.get(user=seller)
msg = userComment(buyer=buyer, seller=p, comment=comment)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CommaSeparatedUserField user field appears to be a custom field that you have not shared with us. However it's easy to see that what your cleaned_data actually a list of seller names rather than `Seller` instances. If on the other hand it contains id, you can just do:

```
msg = userComment(buyer=buyer, seller_id=seller, comment=comment,)
```

if it's just the name

```
sl = Profile.objects.get(name=seller)  # adjust this according to your model
msg = userComment(buyer=buyer, seller_id=sl, comment=comment,)
```